# Is it possible to turn the clock off in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado

How can I turn the `clk off (0)` under specific condition in vhdl using Virtex 7
ex.

Here's a pseudo code:

```
if(x>1)
clk off 
else 
clk on (rising-edge)
```

Comment: Do you want to start and stop the actual clock, or simply enable or disable your clocked circuit (leaving the clock running)?

Comment: my main goal is to save power, so i think the fist choice is the best for me but how to do it ?

Comment: OK Google, ["clock gating Virtex 7"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=clock+gating+virtex+7)... Second hit: [Xilinx WP370 Reducing Switching Power with Intelligent Clock Gating](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp370_Intelligent_Clock_Gating.pdf)

Comment: Use the CE input of `BUG`, `BUFR` or `BUFH` primitives. You should read the clock resources user guide for Xilinx 7-series. Finally, you can shutdown some primitives like `MMCM` and `PLL` with a reset signal. Others like transceivers have dedicated power down ports (`PD`).

Answer (score 2):

With Xilinx 7 series, you can use xilinx clock buffer called `BUFGCE`

[image]

This is a clock enabling buffer which can stop an entire FPGA's area clock circuitry. Have a look at Xilinx [7 Series FPGAs Clocking Resources](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug472_7Series_Clocking.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a "gated clock" which in-general is a not great idea.  If power-savings is the goal, you can accomplish that with a Clock Enable.  What happens with a clock enable is that the clock is still running, but you prevent the logic inside your always blocks (in Verilog) or processes (in VHDL) from toggling their Flip-Flops when the clock enable is turned off.  Here's some pseudo code

```
always @(posedge i_clk)
begin
  if (i_enable)
  begin
    // Lots of code goes here.
  end
end
```

Another neat thing about writing code like this is that you can have a duty cycle on your enable input and that could save some power as well.  If you don't need the logic to run at the full i_clk rate you can pulse enable every so often and the logic will still propagate will less power and less quickly.